# Finding fields in new version of Postman when coming form the older version

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, postman

I am just reading and following my `Web API` book  and this is how the screenshot for Postman settings look like in the book:

[image]

But sounds like that's old and the new Postman I downloaded looks a bit different. Clicking around I found my way BUT my question is: Is this the correct place ? and do I need that "bearer" token still? Because we are picking it anyway in the dropdown.

[image]

Comment: You don't need to add the word Bearer as that would be added to the header, when using that helper.

Comment: ok great. thank you.